# how to customization momentjs months, short Month, Week with CMS text?

Tags: angular, content-management-system, momentjs

Am using Magnolia CMS in my project and Anngular6 in front end where am using moment js for date format conversion. Content controller is willing to customize the date formats text from Magnolia author mode. So I need to replace moment inbuilt language text with content controller provided Month Name/short Month Name from Angular. How to achieve.

Example:

lang: Poland - pl //content controller will set these values in dialogue box

```
var "month":  ['STYCZ',  'LUT',  'MAR',  'KWIE',  'MAJ',  'CZERW', 'LIP',  'SIERP',  'WRZES',  'PAZDZIER',  'LISTOPAD',  'GRUD'] //Some custom Values
```

Angular Needs to inject this values to momentjs library. But am not able to find momentjs syntax to replace the month Name with default moment month name.

Answer (score 0):

Able to update using below code:

In Angular after loading the component in oninit we can  override library text (Month Name or short Month Name)with custom text(Content Managed Message) using below code.

```
moment.updateLocale('pl', {
    months : ['STYCZ',  'LUT',  'MAR',  'KWIE',  'MAJ',  'CZERW', 'LIP',  'SIERP',  'WRZES',  'PAZDZIER',  'LISTOPAD',  'GRUD']
});
```

Month, ShortMonth, Week can also be updated

Refer::
https://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/month-names/